Passing flag in Bash not interpreting correctly
I have tried to find an answer on SO but can not seem to find anything that solves my problem. I am trying to set and pass a flag from one script to a function called within that script.
.test1
#!/bin/bash

source .test2

pass_flag=""

while getopts ":p" opt; do
  case $opt in
    p)
      pass_flag=true
      ;;
  \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

text="this is test text"

cmd=(copy_to_clipboard)               # initial command
if [[ "$pass_flag" = true ]]; then
    cmd+=(-p)          # optional flag, append to array
fi
cmd+=("$text")    # the filename

"${cmd[@]}"

.test2
#!/bin/bash

# Function to copy text to clipboard
copy_to_clipboard() {
    pass_flag=false

    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "Received $arg"
    done

    while getopts ":p" opt; do
        case $opt in
            p) pass_flag=true ;;
            ?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))

    # Check if text argument is provided
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo echo "No text provided. Usage: copy_to_clipboard 'text to copy'"
        exit 1
    fi

    text="$1"
    echo "pass_flag set to $pass_flag"

    if [ "$pass_flag" = true ]; then
        echo "passing, not printing text"
    else
        printf '%s' "$text" | tee >(xclip -selection clipboard)
        printf "\n\nText has been copied to clipboard.\n"
    fi
}

I would expect the command ./.test1 -p to return passing, not printing text. But instead, I get:
Received -p
Received this is test text
pass_flag set to false
this is test text

Text has been copied to clipboard.

Even though I can see that -p is being passed to the function call, getopts is not interpreting it and switching the pass_flag to true. I'm not sure what I'm missing - any help would be appreciated.

Possible duplicate of "Using getopts inside a Bash function".

Upvoted for providing shellcheck-clean code!

Since you invoke getopts multiple times in a single shell execution environment, you'll need to reset OPTIND to 1 (in the called function). See this for the syntax and more explanation.
Also, man for getopts discusses this as well.
#!/bin/bash


copy_to_clipboard() {
    pass_flag=false


    #################
    # ADD THIS LINE #
    #################
    OPTIND=1
    
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "Received $arg"
    done

    while getopts ":p" opt; do
        case $opt in
            p) pass_flag=true ;;
            ?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1 ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))

    # Check if text argument is provided
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo echo "No text provided. Usage: copy_to_clipboard 'text to copy'"
        exit 1
    fi

    text="$1"
    echo "pass_flag set to $pass_flag"

    if [ "$pass_flag" = true ]; then
        echo "passing, not printing text"
    else
        printf '%s' "$text" 
        printf "\n\nText has been copied to clipboard.\n"
    fi   
}

pass_flag=""

while getopts ":p" opt; do
   case $opt in
      p)
         pass_flag=true
         ;;
      \?)
         echo "bad input"
         exit 1
      esac
done

text="this is test text"

cmd=(copy_to_clipboard)
if [[ "$pass_flag" = true ]]; then
    cmd+=(-p)          # optional flag, append to array
fi
cmd+=("$text") 

"${cmd[@]}"

Output without OPTIND=1
$ ./test4.sh -p
Received -p
Received this is test text
pass_flag set to false
this is test text

Text has been copied to clipboard.

Output with OPTIND=1
$ ./test4.sh -p
Received -p
Received this is test text
pass_flag set to true
passing, not printing text

Note in the referenced first link, some commented they had to do an unset - but try the above first.

FWIW I prefer adding local OPTIND to the start of the function so that whatever value OPTIND ends up with inside the function doesn't affect the value of OPTIND in the calling code, unlike using OPTIND=1 or unset OPTIND inside the function. The down side is you end up with a local variable that's all upper case (and effectively 2 variables with the same name OPTIND so if you call another script from the function the OPTIND it gets is the global one, not the local one) but IMO that's the lesser of 2 evils.
